# Django: How to automatically set correct media folder permissions?

Tags: django, linux, apache, permissions, chown

I am running a Django application using Apache webserver.

The media directory is located in `/var/www/app/media/`. Owner of that directory is `www-data:www-data`, so that Apache can read / write to it.

The problem now is that when I run `./manage.py migrate` and a new sub-folder in the media directory is created when I add a new FileField to a model, the owner of that directory is the user running that `migrate` command and I have to fix the owner of that new folder, otherwise Apache can't write to it and I am getting a `Permission denied` error.

How can I set permissions to the folder `/var/www/media/`that user `www-data` can write to any new subfolder, even when that subfolder is created by another user ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do `sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/media/`